# I can't compare correctly a word I read from a file with bufferedreader

Tags: java, file, bufferedstream

I have a program which can recognize specific words from a file .txt

The problem is when find a word I send it to a method like "value" and I question:

```
if (value == "specificword") {...}
```

this question is always false. I have made many debugs and I'm sure both are the same word (without a space or tab or enter) so: Is it possible this be a problem with the text format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `equals` method for string comparision. Change this

```
if (value == "specificword") {...}
```

to

```
if (value.equals("specificword")) {...}
```

`equals` method compares the string contents while == checks for object equality. Read this related post for more info:

[Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: :P tanks I can't belive it n___n